# async nodejs метод each

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Есть записи в mongoose колекции Account и Note. Мне нужно в цикле перебрать все записи базы, записать в масив и отправить в шаблон.

Делаю так:

```js
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var route = 'main/account';
  Account.find(function(err, accounts) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
      (function(index) {
        var result = {};
          Note.findById(accounts[index].note_id, function(err, notes) {
            if (err) return console.error(err);
            result.id = accounts[index].id;
            result.email = accounts[index].email;
            result.name = accounts[index].name;
            result.password = accounts[index].password;
            result.password_email = accounts[index].password_email;
            result.secret_pin = accounts[index].secret_pin;
            result.secret_email = accounts[index].secret_email;
            result.fio = accounts[index].fio;
            result.ip = accounts[index].ip;
            result.live_time = accounts[index].live_time;
            result.body = notes.body;
            result.priority = notes.priority;
            result.status = accounts[index].status;
            data.push(result);
          })
        if (index === accounts.length - 1) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            res.render(route, {
              title: 'BotSC',
              route: route,
              data: JSON.stringify(data),
              javascript: "account",
              user: req.user
            });
          }, 200);
        }
      })(i);
    }
  });
});
```

Но записи выводит на странице в разброс (записи выводятся в таблицу) и при каждой перезагрузке страницы порядок вывода меняется. Как можно подправить этот код?

Comment: Добавить порядок сортировки записей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему так:

```js
router.get('/', forAdminsOnly, function(req, res, next) {

  var route = 'main/account';
  Account.find(function(err, accounts) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    var data = [];
    async.map(accounts, function(account, callback) {
      var result = {};
      if (!!account.note_id) {

        Note.findById(account.note_id, function(err, notes) {
          if (err) return console.error(err);
          result.id = account.id;
          result.email = account.email;
          result.name = account.name;
          result.password = account.password;
          result.password_email = account.password_email;
          result.secret_pin = account.secret_pin;
          result.secret_email = account.secret_email;
          result.fio = account.fio;
          result.ip = account.ip;
          result.live_time = account.live_time;
          result.body = notes.body;
          result.priority = notes.priority;
          result.status = account.status;
          //data.push(result);
          callback(null, result)
        })
      } else {
        result.id = account.id;
        result.email = account.email;
        result.name = account.name;
        result.password = account.password;
        result.password_email = account.password_email;
        result.secret_pin = account.secret_pin;
        result.secret_email = account.secret_email;
        result.fio = account.fio;
        result.ip = account.ip;
        result.live_time = account.live_time;
        result.body = "";
        result.priority = "";
        result.status = account.status;
        //data.push(result);
        callback(null, result)
      }
    }, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("error");
      }
      res.render(route, {
        title: 'BotSC',
        route: route,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        javascript: "account",
        user: req.user
      });
    });

  });
});
```